# Defining constants in UML class diagram interfaces?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, use-case, sequence-diagram, activity-diagram

- is it allowed to define constants in **class diagram interfaces** ?

> like for example a constant that represents the number of how many
>   time a function was invoked in a particular class.

Answer (score 0):

An interface bundles attributes and operations. It's up to you if you make an attribute a constant value. So: yes, it is allowed.